# call ansible from bamboo on a remote machine

Tags: command, ansible, bamboo

I have a Bamboo master instance B, an Ansible master insatnce A with an agent of Bamboo B. I want to trigger ansible command on A to do some remote activity on a target server C. How can I ensure teh ansible comamnd is run on the bamboo agent A rather than Bamboo master B. 
My Command:

```
ansible-playbook callAppserver1.yml -u devops --sudo --vault-password-file=vault.txt --extra-vars "version=${bamboo_planRepository_branch}_${bamboo.buildNumber}"
```

Currently I'm calling ansible command from a script task. which is failing with message "ansible-playbook: command not found". Any ideas appreciated !

1. Should I have ansible in my Bamboo master B ?
2. Should Ansible and Bamboo be on same master ?
3. Can't we trigger the command task on agent ?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use SSH Task in bamboo to invoke ansible playbook. This worked perfectly for me !